# How to enable autocomplete when pressing enter in VS C#

Tags: c#, autocomplete, intellisense, visual-studio-mac

I want that Visual Studio Intellisense accept the suggested keyword after pressing enter. I could not find any option to toggle that.

By Default you can autocomplete the suggested keyword by pressing space or tabulator or an interpunctation.

I edited the settings.json in $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json on MacOs

```py
{
    "telemetry.enableTelemetry": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",


    /* Controls if suggestions should be accepted on 'Enter' - in addition to 'Tab'. 
    Helps to avoid ambiguity between inserting new lines or accepting suggestions.
    The value 'smart' means only accept a suggestion with Enter when it makes a textual change
    */
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "on"
}
```

I expected that after saving the settings.json and restarting the Editor the changes are applied but nothing changed.

Comment: _I want that Visual Studio Intellisense accept the suggested keyword after pressing enter. I could not find any option to toggle that_ - isn't it this one? https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5Hu5.png

Comment: Hi, thats look good but my setting window looks different. this is my window https://imgur.com/bIk4Yp2
My settings editor does not look like this settings editor : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought you meant VS Code. Are you using an old version of VS/Mac?  I see the same settings as you, but using Enter for autocomplete works. My installation doesn't have "Community" in the title bar though - https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvR6P.png

Comment: One other thing - I thought you were using VS Code as `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json` is that app's settings file - https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9Ep8.png. I don't know where VS/Mac stores it's settings, or whether the file is user-editable. As a long-term VS user, I suspect not..

Comment: Ohh i made the mistake to view the Visual studio Code website but iam using "Visual Studio". The error that should have been fixed still exist in my newest version. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/41831/c-autocomplete-enter-inserts-new-line-instead.html the link could not help me.

Comment: I reinstalled VS and the autocomplete with enter works BUT it also works with the space bar. if i go to VisualStudio -> preferences -> intellisense and uncheck the box "complete with space and interpunctation" the enter autocomplete will no longer work. how to fix that?